# BASH Linux exit read log until specific string

Tags: linux, string, bash, awk

I must read the log until I receive “`Server Startup`”.

When I get the string “`startup`”, I must exit the `tail` command and proceed through the rest of the script operations.

Now the syntax is:

```
cd /opt/path/path/path
LOG_FILE=$(ls -ltr | tail -1 |awk '{print $9}')
tail -f $LOG_FILE
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: using `ls -lrt` is not a good idea to find latest file in directory. What is your latest file name contains space ? something like `"latest file"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
stdbuf -oL tail -f log.file | stdbuf -iL awk '/startup/ {print "Match found";exit}'
```

This will check for string `startup` and when it is found, it will print "Match found" and then exit from log monitoring. `stdbuf` to provide line buffered to tail and awk.

Comment: I recommend to use `stdbuf` to force `tail` to write line buffered and `awk` to read stdin line-buffered. Otherwiese the script would have to wait until the IO buffer get's flushed. Like this: `stdbuf -oL tail -f log.file | stdbuf -iL awk ...`

Comment: @hek2mgl ,thank you. Point noted.

Comment: thanks for your availability